# Show year once using MYSQL Distinct and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I have a table (news) with a date row. It contains dates in the format (yyyy-mm-dd). I want to list only the years once on my PHP page, but it's not working. I get an error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

What am i doing wrong?

```
    <?php
       include 'includes/connect.php';
       $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) FROM news ORDER BY date DESC";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);

       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $year = $row->date;
         $echo "$year<br />";
       }
    ?
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of $row and you will probably find that it is not what you are expecting.

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: is it definitely including connect.php succesfully? var_dump($conn) to check it is actually loading a connection

Answer (score 1):

Provide an alias to the query as the alias is easier to identify than the statement, providing a pseudo name to the column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) AS mydate
```

Then, since you're fetching an associate array use the array notation:

```
$year = $row['mydate'];
```